# Fuzzy matching in R; matching user identifiers and adding prefix to matched user identifiers

Tags: r, match, fuzzy-comparison

I am doing secondary data analysis on a user generated log data set and I have noticed that there are 2 different user identifier for the one user; the main difference is that there is an additional prefix in front of the duplicated identifier.

Here is a mock dataframe describing what I mean:-

```
UserId<-c("+cbeed1382f", "+f50197eebb", "+c3e6a4cbc9", "+27bc490129", 
          "+adcadf6cd4", "+e10ca42ce8", "+1744b26118", "+de1e9f6506", "+8aac93c8fd", 
          "+72bed51a4a", "+6a6c7d444b", "+8636fdc4c7", "+6fa2d04df3", "+d4e9b6cf42", 
          "+536fa504a2", "+353cbeed1382f", "+353f50197eebb", "+353c3e6a4cbc9", 
          "+35327bc490129", "+353adcadf6cd4", "+353e10ca42ce8", "+3531744b26118", 
          "+353de1e9f6506", "+3538aac93c8fd", "+35372bed51a4a", "+3536a6c7d444b", 
          "+3538636fdc4c7", "+3536fa2d04df3", "+353d4e9b6cf42", "+353536fa504a2")

Value<-c(8995L, 8746L, 9920L, 4765L, 2489L, 4894L, 2486L, 4782L, 5632L, 
         7784L, 5642L, 3642L, 1123L, 2036L, 2561L, 963L, 562L, 214L, 365L, 
         785L, 465L, 211L, 111L, 256L, 234L, 895L, 441L, 25L, 698L, 478L)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(UserId,Value))
View(df)

df

           UserId Value
1     +cbeed1382f  8995
2     +f50197eebb  8746
3     +c3e6a4cbc9  9920
4     +27bc490129  4765
5     +adcadf6cd4  2489
6     +e10ca42ce8  4894
7     +1744b26118  2486
8     +de1e9f6506  4782
9     +8aac93c8fd  5632
10    +72bed51a4a  7784
11    +6a6c7d444b  5642
12    +8636fdc4c7  3642
13    +6fa2d04df3  1123
14    +d4e9b6cf42  2036
15    +536fa504a2  2561
16 +353cbeed1382f   963
17 +353f50197eebb   562
18 +353c3e6a4cbc9   214
19 +35327bc490129   365
20 +353adcadf6cd4   785
21 +353e10ca42ce8   465
22 +3531744b26118   211
23 +353de1e9f6506   111
24 +3538aac93c8fd   256
25 +35372bed51a4a   234
26 +3536a6c7d444b   895
27 +3538636fdc4c7   441
28 +3536fa2d04df3    25
29 +353d4e9b6cf42   698
30 +353536fa504a2   478
```

So as you can see, the identifier in row 1 ("+cbeed1382f") is the same identifier in row 16 ("+353cbeed1382f") but without the "+353" prefix, row 2 is the same as row 17, and so on. This could be problematic if, for instance, I was doing k-means clustering on this type of data because it would treat the one user as two thus heavily skewing the results.

What I want to do is match these identifiers and if there is a match, the additional prefix (in this case "+353") will be added on. There is one caveat: some of the prefixes are either 3, 4 or 5 digits longs and do not necessarily begin with "+353". So the solution would need to be aware of this. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Does every base id start with a letter? Does every prefix contain only numbers?

Comment: Hi @BrianLang every base id can either start with a number or a letter (with a + symbol before).

Comment: Ah I see that now. Is there a regular number of characters for a base id?

Answer (score 0):

This will strip out any numbers that are prefixed with a "+" and are followed by a letter, thus giving you your base identifier.

```
df %>% 
 dplyr::mutate(base_id = stringr::str_remove(UserId,
                                             pattern = "(?<=\\+)[0-9]+(?=[a-z])")) %>% 
 dplyr::arrange(base_id)
```

However, this will over-shorten your base-ids.

In your example you have that the last 10 characters are the base id. In this case you could extract the base with this:

```
df %>% 
 dplyr::mutate(base_id = stringr::str_remove(UserId,
                                             pattern = "(?<=\\+)[0-9]+(?=[a-z0-9]{10}$)")) %>% 
 dplyr::arrange(base_id)
```

specifically selecting anything that comes in front of 10 characters of [a-z] and [0-9]

```
           UserId Value     base_id
1     +1744b26118  2486 +1744b26118
2  +3531744b26118   211 +1744b26118
3     +27bc490129  4765 +27bc490129
4  +35327bc490129   365 +27bc490129
5     +536fa504a2  2561 +536fa504a2
6  +353536fa504a2   478 +536fa504a2
7     +6a6c7d444b  5642 +6a6c7d444b
8  +3536a6c7d444b   895 +6a6c7d444b
```